# Possible bug in IIS url rewrite module or is it just me?

Tags: iis, rewrite

Okay, so I came up with the brilliant idea to run a W2012 IIS8 with rewrite rules to do some reverse proxying for me, not because it's the best choice, but because I didn't want yet another box solving yet another problem.

I managed to get it all up running all very beautifully with two subdirectories linking to two backend Linux servers, and all outbound tags seemed to be rewritten just like the should be.
Until I tried to login and realized that it skipped some form fields.

After a long night I managed to find what triggered the rewrite engine not to handle the forms in this case and it more had to do with attributes which had an hyphen or underscore in it. The forms that my Linux sites were produceing contained the line

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/login" ...
```

which of course contained an hyphened attribute.

So, I set out to nail it down and came up with this:

/test/default.htm

```
<html>
    <a href="/ahrefpage.htm">This ahref has no dummy attribute</a>  </br>
    <a dummy="x" href="/ahrefpage.htm">This ahref has a dummy attribute</a> </br>
    <a dum-my="x" href="/ahrefpage.htm">This ahref has a hyphen dummy attribute</a> </br>
    <a dum_my="x" href="/ahrefpage.htm">This ahref has an underscore dummy attribute</a>    </br>
</html>
```

with the following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="OutboundRewriteTestPage" preCondition="isHtml" enabled="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" customTags="" pattern="^/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/test/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="isHtml">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
                <customTags>
                </customTags>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So, the resulting page was this

```
This ahref has no dummy attribute           https://portal.xx.com/test/ahrefpage.htm
This ahref has a dummy attribute            https://portal.xx.com/test/ahrefpage.htm
This ahref has a hyphen dummy attribute     https://portal.xx.com/ahrefpage.htm
This ahref has a underscore dummy attribute https://portal.xx.com/ahrefpage.htm
```

So basically the question is, is this yet another bad implementation by MS of a technology that works well on Linux, or have I missed something? 
Is there a workaround - except for modifying the source material, which defeats the purpose.

Thanks,
Chris.J

Comment: ..but what I did notice now is that if I place the hyphened attribute after the href, then it is processed properly.
This is probably working out as it then can rewrite the attribute successfully before it goes wrong.
So.. the problem is still there, but we're one step closer ;)

Comment: So I managed to resolve this and posted the solution over at IIS.net.
In the end it all had to do with a known by Microsoft bug.

**[Link to forum post](http://forums.iis.net/post/2057565.aspx)**